# What wrong with build APK and App bundle?

Tags: flutter, android-gradle-plugin, apk, android-app-bundle

I was looking to build the APK and App Bundle. I need to create Apk of the project through android studio Build>>Build Bundle(s) /APK(s)>>Build Apk(s). But when I do this it gives me the following error
I have tried every solution on internet eg invalidate caches and restart, clean project

```
Building with sound null safety 

Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                        

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.google.android.material:material:<version>.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Could not resolve com.google.android.material:material:<version>.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/material/material/%3Cversion%3E/material-%3Cversion%3E.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/material/material/%3Cversion%3E/material-%3Cversion%3E.pom'. Received status code 400 from server: Bad Request

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 53s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           57.3s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                        [!] Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network. Retrying to download...


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.google.android.material:material:<version>.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Could not resolve com.google.android.material:material:<version>.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/material/material/%3Cversion%3E/material-%3Cversion%3E.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/material/material/%3Cversion%3E/material-%3Cversion%3E.pom'. Received status code 400 from server: Bad Request

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 15s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           17.4s
[!] Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network. Retrying to download...
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

did you integrating Firebase Cloud Store in your project? If yes then Inside the project level gradle, you should add:-

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
```

Comment: No i not using firebase

Answer (score 0):

It's trying to find the SDK `com.google.android.material:material:<version>`. As you can see, the version is not specified.

If you replace `<version>` with the actual version you want (e.g. `1.4.0`), this should resolve your issue.

Don't forget to add `google()` in the list of Maven repositories since that's where this library is published.